# sort pandas dataframe of month names in correct order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with names of months of the year, I.e. Jan, Feb, March etc

and I want to sort the data first by month, then by category so it looks like

```
Month_Name | Cat
Jan          1
Jan          2
Jan          3
Feb         1
Feb          2
Feb         3
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` doesn't do custom sort functions for you, but you can easily add a temporary column which is the index of the month, and then sort by that

```
months = {datetime.datetime(2000,i,1).strftime("%b"): i for i in range(1, 13)}
df["month_number"] = df["month_name"].map(months)
df.sort(columns=[...])
```

You may wish to take advantage of `pandas`' good date parsing when reading in your dataframe, though: if you store the dates as dates instead of string month names then you'll be able to sort natively by them.

Comment: thanks katrielalex, so it would be better for me to start with a date like 2014-11-30, and then create a new column based on that. Is it possible to sort by the date column, but then hide it when I am presenting the data in the notebook. So if I had two columns, one with the date and the other with month name, can you say "sort by date, only show month_name?

Comment: Why don't you just sort by the full date column, and then create another with the month name for display?

Comment: yeah, just `print df[columns]` instead of `print df`

Answer (score 0):

Use **Sort_Dataframeby_MonthandNumeric_cols** function to sort dataframe by month and numeric column:

You need to install two packages are shown below.

```
pip install sorted-months-weekdays
pip install sort-dataframeby-monthorweek
```

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

from sorted_months_weekdays import *

from sort_dataframeby_monthorweek import *

df = pd.DataFrame([['Jan',23],['Jan',16],['Dec',35],['Apr',79],['Mar',53],['Mar',12],['Feb',3]], columns=['Month','Sum'])
df
Out[11]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   23
1   Jan   16
2   Dec   35
3   Apr   79
4   Mar   53
5   Mar   12
6   Feb    3
```

To get sorted dataframe by month and numeric column I have used above function.

```
Sort_Dataframeby_MonthandNumeric_cols(df = df, monthcolumn='Month',numericcolumn='Sum')
Out[12]: 
  Month  Sum
0   Jan   16
1   Jan   23
2   Feb    3
3   Mar   12
4   Mar   53
5   Apr   79
6   Dec   35
```