# Sorting a column by date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort this 'Month' column within my 'Mon18' table to run from January through to December with its corresponding count. When I try sort the column it orders it either by highest count or by sorting the 'Month' Column alphabetically. See an example below:

```
print (df)
            Months  Count
10      April 2018    684
3      August 2018   1098
1    December 2018   1207
11   February 2018    642
8     January 2018    847
5        July 2018   1040
6        June 2018    986
9       March 2018    809
7         May 2018    854
0    November 2018   1215
2     October 2018   1128
4   September 2018   1062
```

Comment: please try to include code snippets directly instead of including screenshots

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179082/sort-pandas-dataframe-of-month-names-in-correct-order/48959467

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort pandas dataframe of month names in correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27179082/sort-pandas-dataframe-of-month-names-in-correct-order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is convert column to datetimes and use [`Series.argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argsort.html) for indices passed to [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df['Months'], format='%B %Y').argsort()]
print (df)
            Months  Count
8     January 2018    847
11   February 2018    642
9       March 2018    809
10      April 2018    684
7         May 2018    854
6        June 2018    986
5        July 2018   1040
3      August 2018   1098
4   September 2018   1062
2     October 2018   1128
0    November 2018   1215
1    December 2018   1207
```